# Custom NamingStrategy on QueryDSL Maven plugin

Tags: querydsl

I created a class extending it from DefaultNamingStrategy. I referenced it in maven plugin like this:

```
<namingStrategy>com.myproject.MyCustomNamingStrategy</namingStrategy>
```

But I'm getting "ClassNotFound" exception. Is it possible to write a custom NamingStrategy class? If yes, how do I declare it in maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This [PR](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/2016) introduced the ability to change the name-mappings in runtime, when the `Configuration` is created:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(templates);
configuration.setDynamicNameMapping(new ChangeLetterCaseNameMapping(ChangeLetterCaseNameMapping.LetterCase.LOWER, Locale.getDefault());
```

The [`ChangeLetterCaseNameMapping`](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.2.1/apidocs/com/querydsl/sql/namemapping/ChangeLetterCaseNameMapping.LetterCase.html) is already provided by Querydsl and useful for PostgreSQL for instance, but you can implement your own `NameMapping`.

Comment: This is probably a late answer, but thought it might be useful nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the `ClassNotFoundException` by adding my project as a dependency of the build profile that generates the QueryDSL classes. I'm not sure if this is a good idea but I could not find any other way to make it work.

```xml
<profile>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.querydsl<groupId>
        …
        <configuration>
          …
          <namingStrategyClass>com.myproject.MyCustomNamingStrategy</namingStrategyClass>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            … project where MyCustomNamingStrategy is defined
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      <profile>
    <build>
  <plugins>
<plugin>
```